# File sharing fiasco. Dancing the samba mambo

Tags: networking, kubuntu, samba

I have three computers on a home network and I would really like to share some files but am having challenges.  Your help is requested.

Allow me to introduce my three computers:

- (Kathy) Kubuntu 20.04 laptop connected via wifi
- (Leslie) Kubuntu 20.04 desktop connected via LAN cable
- (Windows) Windows 7 laptop connected via LAN cable

My primary goal is for Windows to view files on Leslie, that's all I really need, but so far that is not working.

Leslie can access the shared folder on Kathy, but Kathy can't access the shared folder on Leslie.  Kathy can see Leslie, but when I attempt to view contents I get: "Could not connect to host for smb://Leslie/"
[image]

Windows does not acknowledge the existence of either Kathy or Leslie

I shared the folders on Kathy and Leslie by opening the Dolphin file manager, viewing the folder's properties, selecting the share tab, and ticking the "Allow guests" box as shown in this screen capture:
[image]

On either Kubuntu computer, when I open the Dolphin file manager and click on Network, then "Shared Folders (SMB), I can see both computers.
[image]

My main question is: How do I get Windows 7 to see content on my Kubuntu machines?

Secondly: Is Samba working?  and What is going on here?

Overall, this just seems like a big mess to me.  Hopefully someone out there will be able to see it differently. Thanks for reading.  I look forward to hearing your ideas!

Comment: Windows firewall enabled?

Comment: @Andra I turned off Windows firewall based on your question and it didn't make a difference.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem of discovery: since a couple of years, Windows disables the smbv1 client dialect on new builds and this in turn disables NetBIOS host discovery in its File manager.  This is primary the case for Windows 10.  I do not know about Windows 7.
There is a bug report for that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1831441
The good thing is that you will find there a procedure to install a software on your Katie and Leslie computers, so that windows can browse them.
In a nutshell (copied from previous link):

[1] Download the file:

```
wget https://github.com/christgau/wsdd/archive/master.zip
```

[2] After unzipping it rename the python script:

```
sudo mv wsdd-master/src/wsdd.py wsdd-master/src/wsdd
```

[3] Copy it to /usr/bin

```
sudo cp wsdd-master/src/wsdd /usr/bin
```

[4] A systemd service file is already provided in the package it just needs to be copied to the correct location:

```
sudo cp wsdd-master/etc/systemd/wsdd.service /etc/systemd/system
```

[5] The `wsdd.service` file has to be edited to remove references to the nobody user:

```
#User=nobody
#Group=nobody
```

[6] Then enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start wsdd
sudo systemctl enable wsdd
```

From that point on, you can browse Katie and Leslie from your Windows machine.

Comment: I followed these instructions, but I encountered issues when I attempted to start wsdd.  Please see my new post with all the details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428176/job-for-wsdd-service-failed-because-of-unavailable-resources-or-another-system-e

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I hope I can get wsdd to work.

Comment: I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1.   I had to install samba via "apt install samba", and I was able to install wsdd via "apt install wsdd".  Windows could not see shared folder until I installed wsdd.  Ironically, my machine with 20.04 still can't.

Comment: Thank you for the feed-back.  It is strange you had to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: BTW, in 22.04 running "apt install wsdd" was a single step process.  There was no need to move files or edit their contents.  Perhaps that's obvious, but I wanted to mention it for clarity.