# Job for wsdd.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error

Tags: networking, services

While following the procedure outlined [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1831441), when I ran the command `sudo systemctl start wsdd` the response was `Job for wsdd.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error. See "systemctl status wsdd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

So I checked journalctl which had this to say:

```
Sep 07 19:40:35 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: wsdd.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
Sep 07 19:40:35 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: wsdd.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Sep 07 19:40:35 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: wsdd.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit wsdd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'resources'.
Sep 07 19:40:35 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: Failed to start Web Services Dynamic Discovery host daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit wsdd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit wsdd.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 187013 and the job result is failed.
```

Then I ran `systemctl status wsdd.service` and saw this:

```
wsdd.service - Web Services Dynamic Discovery host daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: resources)
       Docs: man:wsdd(8)

Sep 07 19:18:27 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: wsdd.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
Sep 07 19:18:27 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: wsdd.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Sep 07 19:18:27 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: wsdd.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Sep 07 19:18:27 kathy-Inspiron-3521 systemd[1]: Failed to start Web Services Dynamic Discovery host daemon.
```

Where would you go from here?  Advice requested.

Comment: Did you try ith `sudo`?

Comment: I used "sudo systemctl start wsdd".  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

For this error:

wsdd.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory

Use this solution:

```
sudo touch /etc/default/wsdd
```

Because there is a missing environment variable that you can see here /etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service

EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/wsdd

Answer (score 1):

Hey Kathy (I assume lol)

So, I followed a similar guide and got the exact same error. I also got a solution from the comments.

The one I followed is here: https://devanswers.co/discover-ubuntu-machines-samba-shares-windows-10-network/

So, the default configuration file (/etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service) got changed at some point. Not sure what exactly, but by just replacing everything in the config file with the example in the guide it fixed it.

I like to use GUI editors for this kind of thing, so "sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/wsdd.service" should open it in gedit.

Just in case the guide is gone in the future, here's what that code block contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Web Services Dynamic Discovery host daemon
; Start after the network has been configured
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
; It makes sense to have Samba running when wsdd starts, but is not required
;Wants=smb.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wsdd --shortlog
; Replace those with an unprivledged user/group that matches your environment,
; like nobody/nogroup or daemon:daemon or a dedicated user for wsdd
; User=nobody 
; Group=nobody
; The following lines can be used for a chroot execution of wsdd.
; Also append '--chroot /run/wsdd/chroot' to ExecStart to enable chrooting
;AmbientCapabilities=CAP_SYS_CHROOT
;ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -d -o nobody -g nobody -m 0700 /run/wsdd/chroot
;ExecStopPost=rmdir /run/wsdd/chroot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```